# How do an Undead Lord Cleric’s two 50% healing bonuses combine?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cleric, undead, healing, channel-energy

I'm currently playing an [Undead Lord](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/archetypes/paizo-cleric-archetypes/undead-lord/) (a Cleric archetype) with the variant [*Undeath Channeling*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/variant-channeling).

*Undeath Channeling* enhances the healing of channel negative energy by 50%. At level 8, the Undead Lord gain the *Unlife Healer* class feature, and his channel negative energy heals for an addition 50%.

Would this be calculated as:

- adding 50% then 50% of the adjusted total?
  4d6 +50% +50% (example: 21 + 10 (50% of 21)  + 15 (50% of 31) = 46) 
  adding 50% of the original roll twice;
- or 4d6 +50% +50% (Example: 21 + 10 + 10 = 41)

I'm fairly certain it's the second one, adding 1/2 of the base roll twice, but I'm not sure. Also, with it adding (effectively) an additional 100% to the healing would it just add the full 21 for the two bonuses or would it add 10 twice?

Answer (score 7):

I suggest that the rule on combining multipliers gives the best indication.  The Common Terms of the game are defined on page 11-13 of the Core Rulebook.  On page 12:

> Multiplying:  When you are asked to apply more than one multiplier to
>   a roll, the multipliers are not multiplied by one another.  Instead,
>   you combine them into a single multiplier, with each extra multiplier
>   adding 1 less than its value to the first multiple.  For example, if
>   you are asked to apply a x2 multiplier twice, the result would be x3,
>   not x4.

A 50% increase can be considered to be a x1.5 multiplier.  So two 1.5 multipliers translate into a x2 multiplier, ie the second solution in your question.  This would mean that as it is a 100% multiplier, you would add 21 rather than add 10 twice.